# My Express Router is getting called twice. Why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

I am calling server.js which calls index.js(via route). The index.js file contains a router that gets called twice, and I want to know why the message "/" (Console.log inside router.use(async (req, res, next) => { from index.js ) is shown twice from index.js when that page is called. I want the router to be called only once. Since I am calling the page only once.

Here is the code for server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const categoryService = new CategoryService(path.join(__dirname, 'data', 'categories.json'));
const routes = require('./routes/index')({ categoryService });
const app = express();

app.use((request, response, next) => {
  response.locals.homeVar = 'Home';
  next();
});

app.use((request, response, next) => {
  cookieSession({
    name: 'session',
    keys: ['ABC', 'DEF'],
    maxAge: 1 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // 24 hours
  })(request, response, next);
});

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.locals.siteName = 'Together Mart';
app.use(routes);

app.use((request, response, next) => {
  next(createError(404, 'File not found'));
});

app.use((err, req, res) => {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.locals.error = err.message;
  res.locals.errorStatus = err.status;

  res.locals.errorStack = err.stack || '';

  if (err.status === 404) {
    res.locals.error = `The requested file '${req.originalUrl}' could not be found`;
  }

  if (err.name === 'CssSyntaxError') {
    res.locals.error += `\n\nError in file '${err.filename}', line ${err.line}, column ${err.column}:\n${err.reason}`;
  }

  if (err.view) {
    res.locals.error += `\n\nError rendering '${err.view}'`;
  }

  console.error(err);

  res.render('error');
});
```

And here is the code for index.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
let categoryData;

module.exports = (params) => {
  console.log('Inside index.js'); 
  let categoryList = null;

  router.use(async (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.path);
    if (!categoryList) {
      try {
        const { categoryService } = params;
        categoryList = await categoryService.getNames();
        categoryData = await categoryService.getListShort();
      } catch (err) {
        next(err);
      }
    }

    res.locals.categoryList = categoryList;
    res.locals.categoryData = categoryData;
    next();
  });

  router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('layout/index', { pageTitle: 'Home Page', template: 'index' });
  });

  router.get('/category/:name/subcategories', async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      const { categoryService } = params;
      const subcategories = await categoryService.getSubCategoriesForCategory(
        req.params.name.toString()
      );
      console.log(req.params.name);
      console.log(subcategories);
      res.json(subcategories);
    } catch (err) {
      next(err);
    }
  });

  return router;
};
```

Why is the message "Inside index.js router.use()" shown twice from index.js when that page is called? Can you please help me resolve the issue ?

Note:

1. I can see that localhost:3001/ is called twice from the network tab of the browser.
2. Inside index.js or index.js is called only once. It is the router.get which gets called twice and I want it to get called only once.

[image: Network Tab]
**Network Tab:**

Comment: Because your browser sends two requests. `console.log` the requested path to figure out why.

Comment: Is your page calling `/category/:name/subcategories` route while it loads?

Comment: No the route "/category/:name/subcategories" is not called on load. When user clicks something on page, this gets called.

Comment: I did console.log(req.path). It shows "/" twice

Comment: Add the contents of your index file as well to the question.

Comment: Index.js is already added. I added both server.js and index.js to the question. From server.js, using route I call index.js. Or do you mean the indexejs file which is being called from index.js?

Comment: Go look in the network tab of the browser's debugger and see EXACTLY which requests are being sent from the browser.

Comment: I can see that my "/" is called twice in the network tab. I have called only once. Not able to get why the same page is called twice

Comment: I have also added network tab in the question for reference

Answer (score 0):

The issue was because browser was calling favicon.ico. I did 2 things to resolve the issue.

1. Deleted the favicon.ico file.
2. Added the line for link as  link rel="shortcut icon" href="data:image/x-icon;,"type="image/x-icon" in my ejs